# How do I access the integral symbol "\int" after renewcommanding "\int" to something else?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

I like to define "\int" to be \operatorname{int}, where int refers to the interior automorphism defined by an element of a group.

This is good for me because integrals never appear in my writing... except sometimes they do. Is there a way to access the integral symbol (usually accessed by $\int$) after you renewcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}} ?

Comment: The usual term is *inner automorphism*, rather than interior.

Comment: @egreg I agree, but somehow the shorthand "int" appears in a number of sources (often of French origin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\let`. Since you want to redefine `\int` as an operator, you need to "unassign" it first using `\let\int\relax`. If you use `\renewcommand`, you don't have to do this, but if you use `\DeclareMathOperator*`, you do.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\oldint\int\let\int\relax\DeclareMathOperator*{\int}{int}

\begin{document}

Here is $\int_{a=1}$ inline. Also, $\oldint_0^1f(x)$, And also displayed:
\[
\int_{a=1}\qquad\oldint_0^1f(x)
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The safest way is to use `\NewCommandCopy`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewCommandCopy{\INT}{\int}
\renewcommand{\int}{\operatorname{int}}
```

If you don't have a recent LaTeX, you can use

```
\let\INT\int
```

(but it's better to update).

However, I wouldn't do it and rather use a different name, for instance

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Int}{int}
```

Comment: Note that the first approach will not work with a package like `unicode-math` that delays declaring its symbols. In that situation, you must wrap the command in `\AtBeginDocument`. Or, use the better solution at the end of your post!